# Add HTML to Term Description

Tags: terms, escaping, categories

I'm trying to add ( using [`wp_editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) ) an HTML Term Description *without a pluign*. Whenever I try and spit out the data I get escaped HTML back:

`&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;` Should be `<strong>test</strong>`

I tried [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) but has unexpected consequences...

`<div class="\&quot;big">Test</div>` Should be `<div class="big blue">Test</div>`

I've tried removing `wp_kses` filters like other answers have suggested but it doesn't seem to have any kind of affect.

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses', 20 );
remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data', 20 );
```

Here's where I'm actually displaying the editor:

```
/**
 * Adds additional fields to terms
 * @param Object $term
 * @return void
 */
function extra_category_fields( $term ) {
  ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        tr.form-field.term-description-wrap {display:none!important;}
    </style>

    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="meta-content"><?php _e( 'Description' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <div id="catContent">
                <style type="text/css">.form-field input {width: auto!important;}</style>
                <?php wp_editor( $term->description, 'term_desc', array(
                        'textarea_name' =>  '_term_desc',
                        'textarea_rows' =>  15,
                    ) ); 
                ?>
            </div>
            <span class="description"><?php _e( 'The description is not prominent by default.' ); ?></span>
        </td> 
    </tr>

  <?php
}
add_action( 'tax_class_edit_form_fields', 'extra_category_fields' );
```

Here's what I'm actually updating the data:

```
/** 
 * Save Term Meta
 * @param int $term_id
 * @return void
 */
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( isset( $_POST['_term_desc'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_term_desc'] ) ) {
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, array( 'description' => $_POST['_term_desc'] ), array( 'term_id' => $term_id ) );
    } else {
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, array( 'description' => '' ), array( 'term_id' => $term_id ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'edited_tax_class', 'save_extra_category_fileds' );
```

Does it have to do with *how* I'm displaying it or *how* I'm saving it? How can I store / save HTML in Term Descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see for getting this to work is running the output through [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) and [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and saving it with [`esc_attr()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr):

Saving the term:

```
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, array( 'description' => esc_attr( $_POST['_term_desc'] ) ), array( 'term_id' => $term_id ) );
```

Showing the term on the front end:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', html_entity_decode( stripslashes( $term->description ) ) );
```

Showing the content in the editor:

```
<?php wp_editor( html_entity_decode( stripslashes( $term->description ) ), 'term_desc', array(
        'textarea_name' =>  '_term_desc',
        'textarea_rows' =>  15,
    ) ); 
?>
```